# Jetty REST API to Dynamically adjust QueuedThreadPool maxThreads

Tags: spring, rest, jetty

It's easy to set min/max threads from jetty configuration:

```
<Configure id="server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">   
<Set name="threadPool">
    <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool">
      <Set name="minThreads">10</Set>
      <Set name="maxThreads">1000</Set>
    </New>
</Set> 
</Configure>
```

I'm using Spring and I have a REST endpoint:

```
@RequestMapping("/setMaxThreads")
public void setMaxThreads(...) {
    ...
}
```

How do I access the Server/ThreadPool objects in order to adjust their parameters?

P.S. I understand that any solution likely won't be very generic since those are very implementation-specific parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't even do what you describe in your `jetty.xml` example anymore.

The `ThreadPool` for a Jetty `Server` is only set [via its constructor](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/Server.html#Server-org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ThreadPool-) now.
It cannot be adjusted during runtime.

> This change from `.setThreadPool(ThreadPool)` to `Server` constructor based occurred at the start of Jetty 9.x, and was to address the threadpool needs of both Servlet 3.1 and HTTP/2 support.

The reason for this, is that the `ThreadPool` is injected into dozens of other layers during initialization of those layers, and even more during `LifeCycle` startup of the `Server`

If your goal is some sort of premature optimization on the upper limits of the thread pool size?

Stop now.

Since Servlet 3.0, bound (upper limited) thread pools make absolutely no sense for a publicly accessible Jetty Server.

You open yourself to trivial DoS attacks, failed selector processing, dead connections, seemingly random EOF exceptions, etc ...

Don't optimize the thread pool upper ends and then expect Jetty to handle a high load scenario.

Under high load scenarios, its not uncommon for the `QueuedThreadPool` to spike (temporarily) to 20,000 or even 50,000 active threads.  When the server load subsides, so will the number of threads that the `QueuedThreadPool` is managing.  The `QueuedThreadPool` will grow thread counts quickly if needed, but the removal of threads from the pool is intentionally metered.

If you are a running Jetty on a very controlled, small load scenario, then feel free to just outright replace the `QueuedThreadPool` with your own declaration. We would suggest you use an [`ExecutorThreadPool`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/util/thread/ExecutorThreadPool.html) which has a `java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService` implementation of your own choice.

An ExecutorThreadPool example:

```java
    int corePoolSize = 400;
    int maximumPoolSize = 1_000_000;
    long keepaliveTimeout = 60L;
    TimeUnit keepaliveUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS;
    BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue = new SynchronousQueue<Runnable>();

    ExecutorService cachedExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(
            corePoolSize, 
            maximumPoolSize,
            keepaliveTimeout,
            keepaliveUnit,
            workQueue);

    ExecutorThreadPool threadpool = new ExecutorThreadPool(cachedExecutor);
    Server server = new Server(threadpool);
```

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to investigate the performance characteristics (throughput/latencies) of a quite complex (back-end / not web) API. One of the experiment is to set maxlimit to +Inf to make sure that every request hits the back-ends ASAP without queueing. Apparently - as you say - this is the default behavior. Great! The web is full of ` server.setThreadPool(pool);` examples. If you could provide a simple `ExecutorThreadPool` example, I think it would nicely conclude this question.

Comment: Jetty being a 21 year old project (started in 1995), the web is full of out of date information about old (EOL/End of Life) versions of Jetty where manipulating the ThreadPool like that was possible.  I'll update the answer with more details.